# How to trace background job ( backburner ) by opentelemetry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, open-telemetry

I try to trace background job by open telemetry like following code

```
# opentelemetry.rb
MyAppTracer = OpenTelemetry.tracer_provider.tracer('admin-export-tracer')


# others code
MyAppTracer.in_span("export sales job", kind: :server) do |span|
  OrderExportJob.deliver(@merchant.id, data[:performer_id], options)
end

# others code
```

is it correct? or I should move tracer to inside of background job?

is anyone could give me some example?